# Can Vim save and restore state for file contents?

Tags: vim

I'm trying to setup a system where I can establish a "checkpoint" in my Vim code contents such that when I hop back to that state by pressing a keyboard command. If anyone has ever played with an emulator then this is effectively what a save state is. It would be ideal if I can jump back to a state and have my buffers, files and the exact file contents (even if they're not the same contents as the files on disk) back to where they were.

This feature is similar to undo, but the state history can be persisted when vim is closed.

Comment: Why not use a revision control system for this? :)

Comment: Yes, but I was hoping that Vim could somehow manage both.

Comment: And it could still work with a project that has it's own SVN system.

Comment: There are plugins in vim for working with git. Not sure about svn but you can call svn commands directly from within vim.

Answer (score 4):

Since version 7.3, Vim has *persistent undo*. You enable this via

```
:set undofile
```

See `:help undo-persistence` for details.

The "checkpoint identifier" can be retrieved via the `:undolist` command, or via

```
:echo undotree().seq_cur
```

You can then go back to that state [N] via `:[N]undo`, or the `:earlier` / `:later` commands. Or use a plugin like [undotree.vim - Display your undo history in a graph](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4177) or [Gundo - Visualize your undo tree](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3304), which offer more comfortable browsers for the undo history.

Note that this state is still per-buffer only, Vim only has the unrelated *session* functionality to group sets of files for editing, but those won't automatically store your checkpoint.

Answer (score 1):

We know what you want but you didn't really explain *why* you'd want it: what problem are you trying to solve? Persistence between sessions? Not knowing how to use undo?

If you want persistence between sessions, you could use [`screen`](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) or [`tmux`](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/). They are terminal multiplexers that allow you (among other things) to put your current session on hold and get it back days later from a different host or whatever:

```
$ tmux
$ vim -O foo.js bar.js
C-b d
(time passes, work is done elsewhere…)
$ tmux attach

$ screen
$ vim -O foo.js bar.js
C-a d
(time passes, work is done elsewhere…)
$ screen -r
```

You could also use Vim's session management:

```
:mksession
(time passes, work is done elsewhere…)
:source Session.vim
(time passes, work is done elsewhere…)
:q
(time passes, work is done elsewhere…)
$ vim -S
```

See `:help :mksession`.